# Intersystems Cache: Querying a table that has a column with data type of another table

Tags: intersystems-cache, intersystems

What is the notation I need to use to extract specific/all row and field information from a field that is of type table (basically an embedded table inside of a field)?

Comment: It sounds like you should be using a join, but it's not clear to me whether that's what you want.
It sounds like you have class Package.A that has a property B of type Package.C, and you want your query to include all the fields of C when you query A. Is that correct?

Comment: In theory a join would be ideal, unfortunately the column isn't of data type int or varchar for example, which could be used in a join to link to another table. It's of type table (another table in the DB), meaning the field basically stores a %collection of rows of that other table.

Comment: Can you post this column (class property) definition?

Answer (score 0):

You can use -> notation.
For example your table name is "Sample.Person" and the "zipcode" is a column of that table that directs to "Sample.Zipcodes"

Example Queries:

```
SELECT *,zipcode->name,zipcode->number FROM Sample.Person
SELECT * FROM Sample.Person where zipcode->name = 'foo bar'
```